# Transform values of a Map in groovy

Tags: groovy

Lets say I have a map `Map<String, List<Integer>>`.

I want to transform this map into `Map<String, Map<Integer, Object>>` by applying `convert()` method for each pair of key and element of nested list.

```
Object convert(String key, Integer value)
```

How can I achieve that?

I tried something like this:

```
map.collect { key, list ->
    key: list.collectEntries {
        [(element): convert(key, element)]
    }
}
```

but I'm getting  `ClassCastException: ArrayList cannot be cast to Map`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not at a computer, but try

```
map.collectEntries { key, list ->
    [key, list.collectEntries { element ->
        [element, convert(key, element)]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Almost computer :) It does not work as is - `key ` and `element` are treated as string literals. But it works after surrounding them with brackets: `(key)` and `(element)`. Could you update the answer?

Comment: They shouldn't be...  That's the list form of `collectEntries`, not the map form

Comment: You have to wrap them if you use them as keys in a map, but I'm not, I'm just using them as the first element in a returned list

Comment: May be the question isn't clear but I want exactly to use them as keys in a map

Comment: Have you tried the code? That's exactly what it does

Comment: You're right. I modified my code according to your example, but It was a little bit different, it didn't have lambda declaration in second `collectEntries` call. `element ->` part was missed.
However it worked after surrounding with brackets.

Comment: @caeus the code doesn't need parentheses, I reverted your edit

Comment: @tim_yates, it doesn't. It creates a map with only one key "key", and with a value that is a map with only one key "element"

Comment: Oh, ok... you're not returning singleton maps, but arrays...

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify it a little:

```
def convert = { it -> it + 1 };
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = [foo: [1, 2, 3], bar: [4, 5, 6]];
map.collectEntries { k, v -> [(k): v.collect { convert(it) }] }
```